# php class structure for presentation

Tags: php, database, class, structure, presentation

I need experienced developers advice on this. Let me get straight into it.

I have users posting articles and i need to show a list of articles and display the users that posted them.

In my curent precedural method its something like this:

```
$result = mysql_getresult("SELECT users.*, articles.* 
                          FROM users JOIN articles ON users.id = articles.user_id
                          WHERE 1");
while($row = mysql_getrow($result)) {
    display_username($row);
    display_articletitle($row);
}
```

Now i want to do it OO method

```
class User {
    protected $data;

    public function loadUserData($id) { $this->data = mysql_readstuff() }
    public function displayUserName() { echo $this->data['name'] }
}


class Article {
    protected $data;

    public function loadArticleData($id) { $this->data = mysql_readstuff() }
    public function displayArticleTitle() { echo $this->data['title'] }
}
```

problems with OO:

1.) These classes has their own methods for loading their own data (and many other methods) so the fast mysql query for getting all the data at once with the JOIN is not really working here. Loading their own data is great for many other methods (eg authentication).

2.) I want to separate presentation (using savant3 templater) so where should i put the display methods? I will need to display a many many things (jobs, comments, etc) and i dont think makeing a method for each of them in the templater is a good idea.

The example is with users and articles, but i will have user + comment, user + job + requirements.

I thought of making the display methods static and let them take a parameter, but then its no different then the procedural method. Or make a setData($row) method that will set the $data to be the parameterthat it got.

Probably there is a common solution for this problem.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you,
Skaccer

Answer (score 1):

An Article class should not have a load method, or a display method.

My advice would be to create a [table gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html):

```
Class ArticleGateway {

    getArticles(){} // returns an array of article objects
    getArticlesByAuthor( Author $author ) {}

}

$articleGateway = new ArticleGateway() {}
$articles = $articleGateway->getArticles();
```

Now `$articles` contains an array of Article Objects. You can iterate over it in your view and display the articles.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a think about it (its my own side project) and get back to you. I need something that can handle paged results, ordered results, fulltext search and non-fulltext search results, and soon adding sphinx as a search enginge too. It need to count results too. [Here is the link to the current page](http://www.networkdance.com/dance-ballet-auditions) - click on the "detailed search" at the right. And it needs to happen on more then one page...

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as @galen said,

Dont let your class methods print out your data, let them return an array of the data, then you handle them as you need to view them:

I experiences this when developing my application. i can use my methods to load an android app data as well as a website application